# Repaired patches in my lawn, fantastic growth, but all died in the first week without rain

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, overseeding

This spring I overseeded patches in my lawn, it was great because right after overseeding there was a period of about a month with daily rains. The results were fantastic, everything grew perfectly.

But after 4 weeks of rain, the fifth week was dry, and all the new grass died. The rest of my lawn, the older grass, had zero problems.

Any suggestions on why it died so early?

I live in a area with temperate-continental climate.

[image]

Comment: New grass needs to be moist almost nonstop.  Here in Ohio, I never repair in Spring, as no matter how well established it is, half of it will die in summer.  I only repair in Fall, as it gets two growing seasons before the next summer.

Comment: Roots take time to get established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely that you used a different of lawn seeds. While they might look similar (the seeds and the grass blades), their behaviors can be very different.

Considering the picture, you probably need a lawn suitable to dry shady areas. It seems that the area is on the northern side of the house.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I had bought seeds specific for dry areas and they manage way better.